# Saving Form Data to Realtime Firebase DB

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my angular app i am having trouble storing my Employee Form Values into Firebase DB..Although the values are saved into a collection in my Firebase DB In Cloud Firestore whereas i want the data to be saved in my Realtime Database.Help me how to do that..
Here's the employee.component.ts onSubmit

```
onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    let data = Object.assign({}, form.value);
    delete data.id;
    if (form.value.id == null)
      this.firestore.collection('employee').add(data);
    else
      this.firestore.doc('employee/' + form.value.id).update(data);
    this.resetForm(form);
    this.toastr.success('Submitted', 'Register done!');
  }
```